# c# compare two columns in datagridview and format third column

Tags: c#

I have 4 columns in datagridview: HomeTeam,HomeScore,AwayScore and AwayTeam.

I want to compare HomeScore and AwayScore column.If HomeScore is greater than Away Score, HomeTeam must be bold. Please help.

Comment: You should read the rules on posting. Please provide code that you have tried.

Comment: You will have to use triggers http://wpftutorial.net/Triggers.html and a coverter to do the comparsion and change the background color. Read more than come back again.

more: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140623/WPF-Tutorial-Styles-Triggers-Animation

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
        DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        style.Font = new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

        for (int i = 0; i==dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++ )
            if ((int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value > (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Style = style;
        }
        else if ((int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value < (int)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value)
        {

            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style = style;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("HomeScore");
            dt.Columns.Add("AwayScore");
            dt.Columns.Add("AwayTeam");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, 1,"Everton");

            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            this.dataGridView1.CellFormatting +=
                new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellFormatting);
        }

        void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex > -1 && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["AwayTeam"].Index)
            {
                e.FormattingApplied = true;
                int home = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1["HomeScore", e.RowIndex].Value);
                int away = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1["AwayScore", e.RowIndex].Value);
                if (home > away)
                {
                    DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

                    style.Font = new Font(dataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
                    e.CellStyle = style;

                }
            }
        }
```

This way every time you update homescore or awayscore the awayteam cell will be updated also.